# Codesign states code object is not signed at all

Tags: macos, terminal, file, code-signing

I have noticed this before too on some executable files. Recently, I downloaded `cmake` and used `codesign` to check if it's digitally signed but it states, it's not signed at all:

```
% codesign -v /Volumes/SanDisk/cmake-3.18.1-Darwin-x86_64.dmg 
/Volumes/SanDisk/cmake-3.18.1-Darwin-x86_64.dmg: code object is not signed at all
```

but when I uploaded the same file on **virustotal**: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9b475fe1e493cebaf3f822322a99d7e10729cadb78efabcf88b32c010b1a9f5d/details
it states that it's digitally signed:

```
Signature Verification
Signed file, valid signature
File Version Information
Identifier  org.cmake.cmake
Authority   Apple Root CA
Date Signed Jul 30, 2020 at 10:02:21 AM
Team Identifier W38PE5Y733

Signers:
Apple Inc.
Apple Inc.
Kitware Inc.
```

Just wondering what's happening here. Your inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The disk image is not signed; the app it contains is. Virustotal is apparently picking up the app signature.

Comment: @GordonDavisson So basically `codesign` can't verify if the apps inside it are digitally signed? It verifies the disk image only?

Comment: `codesign` generally looks at only the specific object you told it to (exception: when you use the `--deep` option, it'll sign or verify nested items inside a bundle). Also, analyzing the contents of a disk image generally requires mounting it; I'm pretty sure `codesign` doesn't have know how to emulate both the disk image mounting mechanism *and* the filesystem inside it (which could be any of a variety of formats).

Comment: @GordonDavisson if possible you can answer this question so that I can mark it as answer. Thanks